# How to add a background to a dialog in Wt (if possible)

Tags: c++, wt

Here I have a WDialog object that pops up on the main stuff. My problem is that it is completely transparent and my dialog is like a bunch of text, line edit, etc over the main window's stuff. Now I thought maybe if I give this dialog a white background or something I could avoid that. Is it possible to do so? Is there a special theme or stylesheet I should be using? (The spin boxes also don't have those little arrows next to them and table contents aren't also properly seperated with lines. Everything's kinda too simple and whacky :)))

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're not properly deploying Wt's 'resources' folder. It's located in the wt sources in wt-x.y.z/resources, and must be made available in your docroot directory. On the browsers, you probably see a number of 404 errors for stylesheets, images, ... referring to the 'resources' folder.